# "GET /static/article/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1700

Tags: django

I encounter error:

```
  "GET /static/article/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1700
```

when attempted to post a request using ajax:

the jQuery was imported as:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

I solved the problem luckily by amending it to

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.js'%}"></script>
```

However,I have little idea how this fixed the bug.

Comment: Just check in your page source which path is created by the Django template. {% static %} prepends the STATIC_URL. If this is different from what you had originally, then that is your explanation. I would always work with the second option btw.

Comment: Could you please transmit the comment to answer? @brunostuyts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check in your page source which path is created by the Django template. {% static %} prepends the STATIC_URL. If this is different from what you had originally, then that is your explanation. I would always work with the second option btw.